# Какие библиотеки на сетях лучше использовать на С++?

Tags: c++, сеть

Здараствуйте, посоветуйте пожалуйста хорошие библиотеки на сетях, которые были бы кроссплатформенные и удобны в использовании. Спасибо.

Comment: Если нужна библиотека для реализации сетевого взаимодействия, то boost.

Comment: что значит "на сетях"???

Comment: значит библиотеки для программирования на сетях

Comment: Программирование на сетях? Вам сети Байеса или какие-то другие?

Comment: Нет, я имел ввиду компютерные сети

Comment: Лучше опишите задачу, которую надо сделать... Тогда станет более понятен ваш вопрос

Comment: enet, кроссплатформенная, удобная и без излишеств

Answer (score 3):

Можно использовать [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/). Она кросплатформенная и достаточно удобная.

Comment: а на tcp/udp можно программировать?

Comment: @Max_Advanced, можно.